# How can I export all Entity Framwork EntityTypeConfiguration mapping classes to a csv with the mapping details of each properties in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csv, ef-fluent-api

Sample Class:

```
public class DocumentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DocumentEntity>
{
    public DocumentMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.ID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.DocumentLocationID)
          .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.DocumentUrl)
         .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.DocumentTypeID)
        .IsRequired();

        this.Ignore(t => t.DocumentType);
        this.Ignore(t => t.DocumentLocation);
        this.Ignore(t => t.Document);
        this.Ignore(t => t.FilePath);
        this.Ignore(t => t.FileType);
        this.Ignore(t => t.TemporaryURL);
        this.Ignore(t => t.DestinationPath);
        //this.Ignore(t => t.DestinationURL);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("DOCUMENT");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("DOC_ID");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("DOC_NM");
        this.Property(t => t.DocumentLocationID).HasColumnName("DOC_REF_LOC_TP_RD_ID");
        this.Property(t => t.DocumentUrl).HasColumnName("DOC_REF_URL");
        this.Property(t => t.DocumentTypeID).HasColumnName("DOC_TYPE_RD_ID");
        this.Property(t => t.DocumentVersion).HasColumnName("DOC_VERSION");
        this.Property(t => t.DocumentReceivedBy).HasColumnName("DOC_RECEIVED_BY");
        this.Property(t => t.DocumentReceivedDt).HasColumnName("DOC_RECEIVED_DT");
        this.Property(t => t.IsDocumentDelivered).HasColumnName("DOC_DELIVERED_FLG");
    }
}
```

I need this to a csv file showing which property maps to which database column so that a CSV contains class name, Property name, Table name, Column name.

Comment: Can you provide a sample formatted output for the content of this CSV file, for example for the properties of DocumentMap class?

Comment: Columns: ModelClass, PropertyName, TableName, TableColumn
Values: DocumentEntity, ID, DOCUMENT, DOC_ID

Comment: @TanyaPetkova can you plase help on this?